# having problems with using fork() in C

Tags: c, fork

Hello I'm trying to figure out how to use the fork method in C. (I'm new to C).

Following [a tutorial](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/fork-in-c-programming-language/) I would expect the following code:

```c
// 62-lab.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  fork(); // 1st fork, output is one line (two expected)
  //fork(); // 2nd fork, output is one line (four expected)
  //fork(); // 3rd fork, output is two lines (eight expected)

  printf("pid: %d\n", getpid());

  return 0;
}
```

to give me two lines with the pids from the two processes. However I only get one line as an output.

Even stranger when I call the fork() method 3 times I get two lines as a result.

### Edit

I also checked if the fork is successful with the following code:

```c
int main() {

  if (fork() >= 0) {
    printf("pid: %d\n", getpid());
  } else {
    printf("Error while forking!");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and the output is still only one line:

```
$ ./a.out
pid: 51582
$
```

### Edit 2

So it seems the problem only appears when the stdout is connected to an eshell buffer in emacs. I ran the same code in other terminal emulators and there it worked as expected. This is odd, but for now I can bypass the problem by using another terminal emulator.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It could be that the `fork()` fails.  You don't check for that possibility.

Comment: Are you sure the output is only one line?  If you are executing this in a terminal, you would expect the output of your program and the new prompt printed by your shell to have a "random" order.  Perhaps you are seeing multiple lines, but they appear after your shell prints a new prompt.  Try adding appropriate `wait` calls to prevent the race condition.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I updated my question with what I think is how to check if the fork was successful. It still seems to be the same problem.

Comment: Prints both pids here.  What platform are you using?  And what is stdout connected to?

Comment: @Toby Speight How can I print both pids when only one is shown? I'm on ubuntu 22.04 and the stdout is connected to an eshell buffer in emacs.

Comment: @TobySpeight I just tried using another terminal (kitty) as an stdout and there I don't seem to have this problem. There I get the expected amount of line.

Comment: Fork splits into two processes.  a parent part, and a child part.   Reread the man page, and find an example that demonstrates the concept.

Comment: It seems I was too terse.  I meant that, when I compiled and ran your code (in an Emacs compilation buffer), both pids were printed.  So there's clearly something environmental that's affecting your results.

Comment: Add a wait loop or sleep at the end.  Also, make sure you terminate messages with a newline.  I'd hazard a guess that the Emacs eshell stops when the process it launches terminated, leaving child processes to sink or swim on their own.  A wait loop means something along the lines of: `#include <sys/wait.h>` and `int corpse, status; while ((copse = wait(&status)) > 0) printf(”PID %d: Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n”, getpid(), corpse, status);`

Comment: Of course, you should keep your `corpse` out of the `copse` and in a suitable grave.  Even near Halloween.  There's a typo in my previous comment, where I missed the `r` in `corpse`.